# How would I convert a picture of a slanted surface into a straight one?

Tags: image-processing, projections

Suppose I took a picture of a whiteboard at an angle. If I could detect where the corners of the whiteboard are, what algorithms and linear projections could I use to convert this slanted view into a "head on" view?

Comment: Check out the answer to [this question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/how-to-unproject-quadrilateral-into-rectangle). You can take any 4 points and transform the quadrilateral between them into a unit square. From there you can simply scale in x and y to the size and shape you want.

Comment: Does the transformation need to be perspective correct ?

Comment: @PaulHK what do you mean by perspective correct?

Comment: For example, if the floor was a huge chess board, we would see squares vanish into the distance. When transforming back to 2d we need to take that perspective into account.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1118321 mentioned, as well as @NathanReed in [this answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/5838/7541) to another question, you can do a perspective transform to transform [any convex quadrilateral to any other](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/).

[OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform) has a good library for doing perspective transformations if you don't want to roll your own.